# HTML markup in mail

Tags: c#, html, email, smtp, markup

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (check() == true)  // True: sends mail
    {
        try
        {
            // Mailmessage wordt gedeclareerd (hiermee kan je mails sturen)
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(); 
            // SMTP server van GMAIL wordt hier aangegeven
            SmtpClient smtpali = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");                

            mail.From = new MailAddress("xxxxxx@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("xxxxxx@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
            mail.Body = "Beste gebruiker";
            smtpali.Port = 587;
            smtpali.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "xxxxxxx");
            smtpali.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpali.Send(mail);
            MessageBox.Show("Mail is verzonden!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Verkeerde combinatie!");
    }
}
```

Hello everyone. I've created a login system in C# and just finished the "resend password" form. This form sends a mail to the user with his password (plain and simple). I was wondering, what way can I use HTML markup in the body:

```
mail.Body = "content here"
```

I tried using:

```
mail.Body = "<h1>content here</h1>"
```

...et cetera but that is ofcourse plain text. Any suggestions for my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [`MailMessage.IsBodyHtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx) to true.

```
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, did the trick! Sorry for asking an easy question.

Answer (score 1):

You should set [IsBodyHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx) to true for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mail.IsBodyHtml = true;` in your code